# ajax checkbox call

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to get an ajax request to tick a box if a certain value is returned.

Basically I have the following code:

```
     for(var id in data) {        
              $(id).val( data[id] );
              if($(newsletter).val( data[newsletter])) {

                       $('#newsletter').prop('checked', true);

              }
     }
```

Now I've tried the following code and no dice.

```
for(var id in data) {        
              $(id).val( data[id] );
              if($(newsletter).val( data[newsletter] == 1)) {

                       $('#newsletter').prop('checked', true);

              }
     }
```

This will tick the checkbox for any result returned however if the value is 1 I would like it to then check the box if another value is returned I'd like it to not be ticked.

If I'm doing something wrong please let me know, as I am new to both jQuery and stackoverflow.

Comment: In the first case you wrote `$(newsletter)` then after it `$('#newsletter')`. Why? Are they different objects? Where id `newsletter` defined? What does `data` contain? Where are the rest of the code? Be more specific!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might work : `if($(newsletter).val() == 1...`
or: `if(data[newsletter] == 1)...`

it seems you have there is a missing assignment: 
maybe you mean `var newsletter = $(id).val( data[id] );` I can't figure it out. Please explain, how newsletter is declared.

Comment: Hi, the array that is returned from json is: `$arr = array( 'input#fname' => $fname, 'input#lname' => $lname, '#emailAddress' => $email, '#newsletter' => $newsletter);
echo json_encode( $arr );` so the code itself is coming from PHP via json.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that `data` is the object returned via AJAX, and that `data[newsletter]` is a valid way of accessing some property of that object, which you want to check the value of.

If so, then the following should work:

```
if (data[newsletter] === 1) {
    $('#newsletter').prop('checked', true);
}
```

Also, the reason that the code `if($(newsletter).val( data[newsletter] == 1)) {` is setting it checked for any value is because what you are actually testing with the `if` is the *return value* from the [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) call, which is a jQuery object, *which is always going to evaluate as true, even if there are no elements that match the selector*.

**Protip:** If you want to check if a jQuery selector matched any elements, test the `.length` property instead.

e.g.

```
if ($('.my_selector:eq(0)').length) {
     alert('Found one!');
}
```